# Why are all messages in the RabbitMQ queue unacknowledged?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a single node RabbitMQ server setup with a single queue called `generated_buckets`. I then have a simple Python consumer to consume messages like so:

```py
def scan_from_mq(server: str, port: int, queue_name: str) -> None:
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=server, port=port))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name)

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print(body)
        time.sleep(1)
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

    channel.basic_consume(queue='generated_buckets', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=False)

    print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press Ctrl+C')
    channel.start_consuming()
```

For some reason, the second I run the consumer **all** messages in the queue become unacknowledged.

Before consumer started:

```
root@rmq0:/# rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages_ready messages_unacknowledged
Timeout: 60.0 seconds ...
Listing queues for vhost / ...
name    messages_ready  messages_unacknowledged
generated_buckets       407     0
```

Right after consumer started:

```
root@rmq0:/# rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages_ready messages_unacknowledged
Timeout: 60.0 seconds ...
Listing queues for vhost / ...
name    messages_ready  messages_unacknowledged
generated_buckets       0       372
```

Is there something simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out this is referred to as [Consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) and it can be limited when setting up the channel. I fixed it with this line:

```py
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=200, global_qos=True)
```

Now there's only 200 unacknowledged messages as the consumer consumes.